# Smooth Page Resizing in Firefox with jQuery After Hiding Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my web application I frequently have sections that need to be collapsed/expanded. I do this with jQuery using the slideDown() and slideUp() methods. They work great. However, in Firefox, if I am scrolled all the way to the bottom of the screen and I collapse a div the screen stutters and flashes as the div disappears and the page is automatically resized by the loss of the element.

Has anyone run into this problem before? I've been working around it by setting a min-height with a generous amount of space for any section that will be collapsible but this seems like an unnecessary solution. Chrome doesn't have this problem and, amazingly, neither does Internet Explorer, both of which smoothly resize the page without any sort of stutter or flashing.

I'm using Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu and I've experienced this problem on earlier versions as well. I have not tested on Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran into this problem before and yes. I have worked around this by setting a mini-height or consider not using a slide effect.